# Escape Key not fired in AngularJS model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to doroolbackView when user press esc.

as described here: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/10/19/exploring-angular-1.3-ng-model-options.html

But the keydown (or keyup) function never called when I press ESC

```
  $scope.cancel = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
      $scope.userForm.userName.$rollbackViewValue();
    }


 <input type="text" name="userName"
               ng-model="name"
               ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
               ng-keyup="cancel($event)" />
      </form>
```

**Full example:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/KQbeSE?p=preview

Comment: Did you wrap your input with `form` element with name attribute of `name="userForm"`?

Comment: because angular is waiting on blur event, action will be performed when you tab off the field, from the example you provided: _"This tells Angular that instead of updating the model immediately after each keystroke, it should only update when the input fires an onBlur event"_

Answer (score 1):

I have tested it, and found that this is a bug with one of my extension, I tested it with Incognito without any extension, and it works great.

If someone else have the same issue, please check it without extensions.